# error al importar módulos npm

Tags: javascript, nodejs, npm

estoy usando la librería [leaftlet](https://leafletjs.com/) para mostrar un mapa, pero en lugar de importar el script en el blade, lo quiero hacer via npm, e instalado la librería via npm con

```
npm i leaflet
```

y para iniciar el mapa, tengo esto en mi blade

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
      integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
      crossorigin=""/>

<style>
    #map {
        height: 40em;
        width: auto;
    }
</style>

<div id="map" class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8"></div>

<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MIAPIKEYDEGOOGLEMAPS">
</script>

<script>
    let L = require('leaflet');
    let map = L.map('map').setView([35.68, 139.76], 13);

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
        maxZoom: 20,
        subdomains: ['mt0', 'mt1', 'mt2', 'mt3']
    }).addTo(map);
</script>
```

sin embargo, no me muestra el mapa y en la consola obtengo el error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

y si reemplazo `let L = require('leaflet');` por `import L from 'leaflet';` entonces obtengo el error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

cuál es la manera correcta para importarla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si vas a usar `require()` debe ser código propiamente NodeJS, es decir, no puede estar en el mismo archivo donde tienes HTML, para el caso de usar `import`, como menciona el error, solo funciona en Módulos, podrías probar de la siguiente forma:

```javascript
    <script type="module">
    let L = require('leaflet');
    let map = L.map('map').setView([35.68, 139.76], 13);

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
        maxZoom: 20,
        subdomains: ['mt0', 'mt1', 'mt2', 'mt3']
    }).addTo(map);
    </script>
```

Como puedes ver, en la etiqueta `script` se especifica que es de tipo module: `type="module"`

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, acabo de probar haciendo eso, pero ahora obtengo Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: Por lo que el `require` es una función predefinida en el entorno de ejecución de NodeJS, puedes probar ejecutando con el comando **node** un archivo que sea .js